# PHP MySQL select all data from monday to friday or select all data from weekdays of last week

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, group-by

I am new to mysql and I was wondering how to select 
data from monday to friday of last week? Assuming that
today is monday. Here's what I tried so far but it returned an empty result:

```
SELECT * , SUM(time) AS total_project_hours
FROM task
WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) BETWEEN 0 AND 4 AND deleted='n'
GROUP BY project_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use DAYOFWEEK http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

```
SELECT * , SUM(time) AS total_project_hours FROM task WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) >= 2 AND DAYOFWEEK(date) <= 6;
```

Comment: it returned an empty result, how can I get the data from monday to friday of last week though? assuming that today is Monday?

Comment: there's also an error in your query, I think there should be a GROUP BY..thanks for the comment though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.project_id, SUM(t.time) AS total_project_hours
FROM task t
WHERE WEEK(t.date) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) AND DAYOFWEEK(t.date) IN (2,3,4,5,6) AND 
      deleted='n'
GROUP BY project_id
```

Comment: it returned an empty result :) thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: @markyorky Add input data ans output data so I can find ehat is the issue

Comment: @SaharshShah can u please tell me how to do this same in codeigniter

Comment: @Rajan Sorry, I'm newbie to codeigniter, so I can't help you for that